# composition relations in Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, function-and-relation-composition

I have provided my solution and I see there are subtle differences to those provide in picture. Is my solution equivalent? Which is more rigorously correct?

[image]

\begin{align}
(S \circ R)^{-1} & = \left\{ \left< z, x \right> : \left< z, x \right> \in S \circ R \right\} \\
& = \left\{ \left< z, x \right> : \exists y \in Y s.t. \left< y, z \right> \in S, \left< x, y \right> \in R \right\} \\
&= \left\{ \left< z, x \right> : \exists y \in Y s.t. \left< z, y \right> \in S^{-1}, \left< y, x \right> \in R^{-1} \right\} \\
&= S^{-1} \circ R^{-1}
\end{align}

Comment: Your first equality is wrong. It suggests that $(z,x)\in (S\circ R)^{-1}$ iff $(z,x)\in S\circ R$. This is false. You must change the second $(z,x)$ into $(x,z)$ to fix it.

Comment: @drhab: ok. Why must we define the order to be $\left< z, x \right>$ in the angle brackets and not to be $\left< x, z \right>$?

Comment: Do you agree that $$(S\circ R)^{-1}=\{(z,x)\mid (x,z)\in S\circ R\}?$$ If so then what is your problem? Of course you are also allowed to write $$(S\circ R)^{-1}=\{(x,z)\mid (z,x)\in S\circ R\}$$which is just a matter of switching $z$ and $x$, but the first way of writing is more convenient in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to show that two sets are equivalent is to show that each is a subset of the other.

Let $z \times x \in (S \circ R)^{-1} \subseteq Z \times X$ be arbitrary. By definition of the inverse on a relation, this means that $x \times z \in S \circ R \subseteq X \times Z$. This means there is some $y \in Y$ such that $x \times y \in R$ and $y \times z \in S$. If $x \times y \in R$, then $y \times x \in R^{-1} \subseteq Y \times X$; similarly, if $y \times z \in S$, then $z \times y \in S^{-1} \subseteq Z \times Y$. Then $z \times x \in R^{-1} \circ S^{-1}$. This shows $(S \circ R)^{-1} \subseteq R^{-1} \circ S^{-1}$.

Now let $z \times x \in R^{-1} \circ S^{-1}$. This means there is some $y \in Y$ such that $z \times y \in S^{-1} \subseteq Z \times Y$ and $y \times x \subseteq R^{-1} \subseteq Y \times X$. These imply $y \times z \in S$ and $x \times y \in R$. Then $x \times z \in S \circ R$ and so $z \times x \in (S \circ R)^{-1}$. This shows $R^{-1} \circ S^{-1} \subseteq (S \circ R)^{-1}$.

Comment: thanks for this approach